# Nodes: oblique pointing

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node

I was able to plot the picture on the right(not the same fruits though):

[image]

I have a problem. The arrow on the left is not correct in my plot. How can I make it oblique?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[inner sep=0pt] (boy)  at (0,0)
{\includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth]{boy.jpg}};

\node[inner sep=0pt] (girl1) at (0,5)
{\includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth]{girl.jpg}};

\node[inner sep=0pt] (girl) at (0,10)
{\includegraphics[width=.150\textwidth]{girl.jpg}};





\node[inner sep=0pt] (tangerine) at (10,0)
    {\includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth]{tangerine.png}};
\node[inner sep=0pt] (grapes) at (10,3)
    {\includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth]{grapes.png}};
%%\draw[<->,thick] (pera) -- (grapes)
   ;
\node[inner sep=0pt] (strawberry) at (10,6)
 {\includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth]{strawberry.png}};
\node[inner sep=0pt] (pera) at (10,9)
 {\includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth]{pera.png}};

\draw[-latex,thick] (girl1) -- (strawberry);


\draw[<->,thick] (girl.west) -- (boy.west);
\draw[-latex,thick] (girl) -- (grapes);
\draw[-latex,thick] (girl) -- (strawberry);
\draw[-latex,thick] (girl) -- (pera);
\draw[-latex,thick] (boy) -- (strawberry);
\draw[-latex,thick] (boy) -- (grapes);
\draw[-latex,thick] (girl) -- (tangerine);
\draw[latex-,dashed,thick] (boy) -- (pera);
\draw[latex-,dashed,thick] (boy) -- (tangerine);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\draw[<->,thick] (girl.west) to[out=-120,in=120] (boy.west);` Your questions would become much more popular, I think, if you were to use some standard graphics which everyone has like `example-image-a` and so on, simply because then everyone could run your code and the answers would be more accessible, too.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Marmot!.

Here is the final version if you wish:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[inner sep=0pt] (boy)  at (0,0)
{\includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth]{boy.jpg}};

\node[inner sep=0pt] (girl1) at (0,5)
{\includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth]{girl.jpg}};

\node[inner sep=0pt] (girl) at (0,10)
{\includegraphics[width=.150\textwidth]{girl.jpg}};





\node[inner sep=0pt] (tangerine) at (10,0)
    {\includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth]{tangerine.png}};
\node[inner sep=0pt] (grapes) at (10,3)
    {\includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth]{grapes.png}};
%%\draw[<->,thick] (pera) -- (grapes)
   ;
\node[inner sep=0pt] (strawberry) at (10,6)
 {\includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth]{strawberry.png}};
\node[inner sep=0pt] (pera) at (10,9)
 {\includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth]{pera.png}};

\draw[-latex,thick,blue] (girl1) -- (strawberry);


\draw[<->,thick] (girl.west) to[out=-120,in=120] (boy.west);
\draw[-latex,thick] (girl) -- (grapes);
\draw[-latex,thick] (girl) -- (strawberry);
\draw[-latex,thick] (girl) -- (pera);
\draw[-latex,thick,blue] (boy) -- (strawberry);
\draw[-latex,thick,blue,fill=blue] (boy) -- (grapes);
\draw[-latex,thick] (girl) -- (tangerine);
\draw[latex-,dashed,thick] (boy) -- (pera);
\draw[latex-,dashed,thick] (boy) -- (tangerine);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am new to this: the site and LateX. I didn't know that it was copied from somewhere else.